# Строчная или прописная: где пролегает грань между прозвищем, обзывательством и сравнением?

Tags: прописная-строчная, ономастика, имена

Существует правило, что имена, прозвища, клички, позывные, псевдонимы и т. п. пишутся с прописной буквы (в составных — соответственно все слова, кроме служебных, а-ля: Чучело; Чёрный Мечник; Тот, Кого Нельзя Называть и пр.). Но как отличить прозвище от обзывательства (то же Чучело) и сравнения, которые пишутся со строчной? Неужто на всё воля автора? А если переводим текст, например с корейского или японского, где вообще нет прописных букв? Сами решаем?

Скажем, в романе один человек постоянно называет другого пингвином: "О, пингвин наш идёт", "Ну ты и пингвин!"... Это прозвище, которое следует писать с большой буквы? А если бы он называл его дураком: "О, дурак наш идёт", "Ну ты и дурак!"... Теоретически же и "пингвин", и "дурак" могут являться ругательствами, которые просто часто повторяются в отношении одного человека. Но не будем же мы считать "дурака" за прозвище и писать с прописной? Причём "пингвин" ещё может считаться сравнением с животным (такой же тучный, неповоротливый и с короткой шеей) вроде "Ах ты лиса какая!", "Знаю я этого тюленя"...

Как же тогда принимать решение, считать подобное прозвищем и писать с прописной буквы (Пингвин) или же считать периодически повторяющимся ругательством/сравнением и писать со строчной (пингвин)? Могу лишь предположить, что эта грань порой настолько тонка, что редактор сам решает, как поступить в конкретном случае, ориентируясь на особенности текста.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

С прописной буквы пишутся **только прозвища**, которые фактически заменяют имена (автор обычно называет настоящее имя героя, но в дальнейшем его не употребляет). Все другие персонажи также используют прозвище в качестве имени собственного, в том числе обращаясь к нему.

Все остальное — это **нарицательные слова** (как дразнилки, так и любые сравнения). Вот недавно мне попалась такая строка: "*А эти тупые **бакланы** на звёзды смотреть не велят*". Посмотрела информацию о бакланах — вроде бы их считают крикливыми, прожорливыми и не очень умными птицами.

А это подходящая  статья на тему **"Прозвища героев художественных произведений".** https://vuzlit.com/868351/prozvischa_geroev_hudozhestvennyh_proizvedeniy

У Платонова главного героя все звали Юшкой (а это тоже прозвище, а не имя).

Comment: Хорошо, а как тогда быть с примером о пингвине (сначала один человек называет так персонажа, потом как минимум двое тоже, вторя ему). Получается, в тексте в какой-то момент строчная должна превратиться в прописную (когда кто-то ещё назвал персонажа так)? Или же, зная текст книги, сразу писать "Пингвин" с прописной, как прозвище, которое придумал 1 человек и вскоре другие подхватили?

Comment: Скорее всего, к началу сюжета он уже Пингвин. Автор может только по ходу действия объяснить, почему он получил такое прозвище.